# Code written using visual studio 2005 C# on vista does not run on new Windows 7 PC using visual studio 2010 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I got this new Windows 7 64-bits PC today. There is an application, which was written using visual studio 2005 C# on vista 64-bits, has to be transferred to this new PC. However, I tried to use visual studio 2010 c # express to run it, and then this error pops up:

```
Unhandled exception has occured in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click Quit. the application will close immediately.
InvalidArgument=Value of "2" is not valid for "SelectedIndex".
Parameter name: Selected Index
***************Exception Text********************
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:InvalidArgument=Value of "2" is not valid for "SelectedIndex"
Parameter name: Selected Index
    at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.set_SelectedIndex(Int32value)
    at CameraTestApp.PTCMeasurement.PTCMeasurement_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:.....
    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean flgnore Visible)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message&m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WindProc(Message&m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WindProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message&m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WindProc(Message&m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(lntPtr hWind. lnt32msg. lntPtr wparam,lnt Ptr lntPtr lparam)
    **********Loaded Assemblies********
```

And then I tried to open it in visual studio 2005 C#, an error shows up:

```
Unable to read the project file "CameraTestApp.csproj". C:\......:The imported project "C:\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import declaration > is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

I also tired to open the project in Notepad and change the `<Import Project=>"$(MSBuildToolsPath)"`
to `"$(MSBuildBinPath)"`. Although I can open it after the change is made, I get some errors like

```
"The imported project "C:\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct and that the file exists on disk"
```

This is frustrating. I don't know which version of visual studio I should be keep trying. And what might be the causes of these errors. 
Plus, I haven't look deep into the code, and I am new in C#. Therefore, I'm not sure if it is the problem of different versions of visual studio, or this new computer setup. The exe file of this app is running properly on the old computer, so I don't think it is because the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your project file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
```

Comment: it says"The target'Build' does not exist in the project"

Comment: Ok, then remove DefaultTargets